# How to get picked 3d object (instead of just the clicked face)?

Tags: three.js

Three.js has examples of getting the clicked face of an object and subsequently highlighting that face. I was wondering how to get the entire object instead of just the face.

Example:
I have many asteroids all rendered in a single buffer. How can I get the clicked asteroid object?

*** Update ***

I think I found a way to achieve object 'picking'. Essentially, I keep a list of the objects in memory. When a object is picked I use that object's point information to do a collision detection against all the objects in the list. The object that is the closest to the intersected point should, in theory, be the object I need.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's a good example [here](http://threejs.org/examples/#webgl_interactive_cubes)

You can achieve that using raycaster to project rays and detect intersections.

This is the part of the code you need for object picking.

```
// find intersections

            raycaster.setFromCamera( mouse, camera );

            var intersects = raycaster.intersectObjects( scene.children );

            if ( intersects.length > 0 ) {

                if ( INTERSECTED != intersects[ 0 ].object ) {

                    if ( INTERSECTED ) INTERSECTED.material.emissive.setHex( INTERSECTED.currentHex );

                    INTERSECTED = intersects[ 0 ].object;
                    INTERSECTED.currentHex = INTERSECTED.material.emissive.getHex();
                    INTERSECTED.material.emissive.setHex( 0xff0000 );

                }

            } else {

                if ( INTERSECTED ) INTERSECTED.material.emissive.setHex( INTERSECTED.currentHex );

                INTERSECTED = null;

            }

            renderer.render( scene, camera );
```

**UPDATE 1:**
If all your objects are merged into a single BufferGeometry:

- Have a look at this example: [webgl_interactive_buffergeometry](http://threejs.org/examples/#webgl_interactive_buffergeometry)
- That will show you how to pick faces, not objects. So my guess is:

  ```
   //pseudo code 
   foreach( object in bufferGeometry){ 
       foreach(face in object){ 
          face.addAttribute ( name[object], attribute[object] ) 
       } 
   }
  ```

So creating a custom attribute for each of your object and passing it to its faces, you could:

- intersect a face
- Get its custom attribute
- Select all faces with that attribute -> the object

I haven't tested it but I guess it should work, let me know :)

Comment: But will this get me the specific picked object that is in a buffered geometry?